# Simple Validation with PHP using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I am new to  `AJAX`, and I want to learn how to validate a form. Suppose, I have a form with two input fields. When I click in submit I want to check the page with a php script. 
When the validation is succesfull I want to redirect to the `action="submitForm.php"`. When one or more fields are not valid according to the `validation.php` I want to stay on the page and gives a error message next to the field.

What is the best way to do that?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="submitForm.php" action="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

submitForm.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["username"];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $_POST["password"];
?>
```

Comment: Not much, I have searched the web for some simple validations parts with jquery but that is to difficult to start with

Comment: best way is to learn it by go through some examples and tutorials in internet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to process the fields before actually submitting the form, you can catch its submit event:

```
<form action="submitForm.php" action="post" onsubmit="return MyValidation()">
```

Then, in your javascript:

```
function MyValidation() {
    var valid = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "validation.php",
        async: false,
        data: { name: $('#username').val(), password : $('#password').val() }
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        if(data == 'true') {
            valid = true;
        }
    });         

    // not valid, return false and show some hidden message
    return valid;
}
```

(you need to add an ID to the `<input>` fields in order for the jquery selectors to work...)

Comment: In `validation.php` I can use like normally the `POST` method?

Comment: Yes, there should be a $_POST["name"] variable and a $_POST["password"] variable available...

Comment: Okay, but how can I return from `validation.php` the `valid` variable? And what is the difference between the part `.done(function( data )){}` and if(valid{ return true })

Comment: you can have validation.php just echo 'true' or 'false', so a string. I've updated my code sample.

Comment: Thank you, but if I understand the variable 'data' grabs all the content of the echo output from validation.php

Comment: yes, and if you use JSON as your datatype for the request, 'data' will be the actual JSON object

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions who might help you

- http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59